# CoreML Model testing giving wrong predictions

Tags: model, coreml

I have trained a model for poisonous plants using XCode Playground, But when i test using Playground UI, results are not accurate 2,3 out of 10 are wrong.
Same results when i use this model in my iOS APP.

Comment: 3 out of 10 wrong is 70% accurate. Perhaps that is not accurate enough for your task but it's pretty good for many other tasks. How many images are you training on? How large are these images? How many images are you testing on?

Comment: 2500 Images with 50 categories, Images are 40K to 60K size.
i am using all 2500 images for test and train both.
250 giving wrong output and 2250 giving right

Comment: By how large I meant the width and height. Also, what sort of training accuracy do you get?

Comment: Training Accuracy is 90% with 10 iterations in case no augmentation applied. Similarly In case no augmentation validation is fluctuating. Sometime with Augmentation Accuracy reduce and level with Validation: results are like this accuracy: 85 validation: 85. But in above case evaluation(Testing the model) results are good specially when you use some images other than the images used for training. Finally Images size are differerent but most images are 600x600

Answer (score 0):

One solution i have found, which is to increase the number of iterations from 10 to 30 while training the model and accuracy improve from 70% to 95%

Now issue is this, when i test with some other images other than the images which used for training, like an image of a cup, as Cup is not a flower but my model say that it is Aloe Flower etc.

Comment: This is normal. If your model is only trained on flowers, you should only use it with images of flowers.

Comment: I have found the solution for this too.
I have done my task in two steps 
1- At first step i have used googleNetPlaces to filter plants and non-plants images 
2- At 2nd Step I have used my own developed model